# What's the intuitive reason for why Markov chains are sometimes called "irreducible"?

Tags: markov-chains, intuition

I understand the basic idea and definition behind the irreducibility of Markov chains (all states communicate), but I couldn't quite figure out *why* we call it "irreducible." What's the motivation for giving Markov chains that label in particular as opposed to some other word? What part of the Markov chain is actually "irreducible"?

Comment: If a chain is reducible, the equivalence classes of mutually reachable states effectively form a sub-chain, which can be analyzed in isolation using the corresponding submatrix.

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't we lose information by doing that, though? For example, if you had a transient state which leads to two communicating recurrent states, wouldn't analyzing the recurrent states and transient state alone remove our knowledge of how they all interact?

Comment: Analyzing the behavior of irreducible subchains allows for at least _some_ reduction of the full analysis. They can be sort of collapsed to a single state from the perpspective of the other states.